# Vagrant provisioning command does not add aliases to ~/.profile

Tags: bash, vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-provision

I have a fairly vanilla Vagrant setup running `trusty64`. It's being configured by a single shell file. Among others, it contains an aliasing of `python3` to `python` and `pip3` to `pip`, respectively:

```
echo "Writing aliases to profile:"
echo "alias python=\"python3\"" >> ~/.profile
echo "alias pip=pip3" >> ~/.profile
. ~/.profile
```

For some mysterious reason, these lines never make it into `~/.profile`. There is no error message, nor any other commotion, it's just that nothing happens. This being 2am, I am fairly sure I'm doing something wrong, I just can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pretty sure you're calling the provisioner with something like

```
config.vm.provision "shell", path: "bootstrap.sh"
```

This works well but its executed as `root` user so all the lines are added for this user only. You want to use the [`privileged`](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/shell.html) option

> `privileged` (boolean) - Specifies whether to execute the shell script
>   as a privileged user or not (`sudo`). By default this is "true".

```
config.vm.provision "shell", path: "bootstrap.sh", privileged: "false"
```

will execute as your vagrant user and will add lines in to `/home/vagrant/.profile` file

Comment: Busted! :D Thank you, that helped.

Comment: Thank you very much! I want to note that with version 2.2.9 I had to use `privileged: false` (without quotes) to get it done.